# virtual-box virtual machines date and time are not update to the present date and time

Tags: date, time, virtualbox, ubuntu-14.04

when virtual-box Virtual Machine's are reverted to snapshot time and date are being followed from snapshot time and date, but I want the present day date and time to be followed by Virtual Machine's and I don't want to synchronize time with my host's date and time. please guide me to a solution. I use Ubuntu 14.04 as a host and Ubuntu 14.04 virtual machines .Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run `sudo ntpdate time.nist.gov` every time you revert to a snapshot

Comment: this did the trick thank a lot, but can you suggest a more automated solution for this. rather than me doing this for every time i do a revert.